# Object error when trying to print index 0 on array with PHP

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and I am getting an error:

```
"Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Confrence as array on line 22"
```

I am trying to take data that is put into an array into a table where you have the number 1 seed in column 1 row 1 and the number 16 seed in column 2 row 1. I do not know if this is the correct logic to go about this, but that is my goal. For some reason it won't echo the first index of the array. This is my code.

```
Class Conference:
<?php

    class Confrence
    {
        public $team1;
        public $team2;

        function loadGame($teamone, $teamtwo)
        {
            $this->$team1 = $teamone;
            $this->$team2 = $teamtwo;
        }

    }

?>


This is my main code.

    <?php print( '<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>' ) ?> 
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>User Selection Page</title>
    </head>

    <?php

        require_once("loadGameClass") or die ("Could not load file");

        $westTeams = array();

        $loadGameClass = new Confrence();

        $loadGameClass->loadGame("(1) Gonzaga", "(16) Southern U");
        $westTeams = $loadGameClass;
        echo $westTeams[0];


    ?>

    <body>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Does `Confrence` class implement `ArrayAccess`?

Comment: Your object is setting team1 and team2 via loadGame() and then you are assigning the object in an array variable, this will never work all you can try by casting the object before assigning to array variable as (array) $loadGameClass;

Comment: Were you able to print the results you wanted to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables for `$westTeams` and `$loadGameClass` reference an your `Conference` object, which is not an array. Therefore, you cannot use notation like `$westTeams[0]`.

If you're planning on populating the class with many teams, you might want to submit an array to the `Conference` class and have that stored.

Class Conference:

```
class Conference
{
    protected $teams;

    function loadTeams($teams)
    {
        $this->teams = $teams;
    }

    function getTeams()
    {
        return $this->teams;
    }
}
```

Regarding putting these in a table, you could use the following code. I'm assuming you have a total of 16 teams.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
<?php
    /* Load your teams in the array */
    $loadGameClass = new Conference();
    $loadGameClass->loadTeams(array(...));
    $teams = $loadGameClass->getTeams();
    for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
        $highSeed = $teams[$i];
        $lowSeed = $teams[((2*8)-1)-$i];
        echo "<tr><td>$highSeed</td><td>$lowSeed</td></tr>";
    }
?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This will output the first seed in the first column, first row and the 16th seed in the 2nd column, first row. The pattern will repeat down to the 8th column.

In my code, the conference class is somewhat useless, as it's just a container for the teams array, but you can add functionality to that class to make it worthwhile.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly! I tested it on an online php code tester and the output did not come out in a table. However it ordered (1)(16) with a break in between each element that it printed.

Comment: Yep, I shouldn't have started a new row for each high and low seed pair. I've edited the answer

Comment: Thank you so much for your help again ginovva320. I fixed the problem of not seeing the table because the border was not set to 1.

Answer (score 1):

The `loadGame` method isn't returning anything, so using `echo` on it all won't do anything.

The error you see is due to the `[x]` syntax being for arrays only, you're using a class.

In the case the class member vars are public so you can use the following in your html:

`$westTeams->team1;`

But you also need to change the class, you have a syntax error:

`$this->$team1` should be `$this->team1`

Comment: What would be the best way to that a class that gets one team and put it into an array and then populate that array within a table?

Comment: What do you mean by table... mysql table or html table?

Comment: A html table. Person below had the output come out correctly, but it did not print in a table.

Answer (score 1):

istead of

```
$westTeams[0]
```

use

```
$westTeams->team1
```

Also use

```
$this->team1
```

instead of

```
$this->$team1
```